# How to display a Swift View programmatically from MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, view

Under Xcode 15, I have developed an application for MacOS that computes data, and upon completion, I am able to plot the data to a separate window using the Window menu.  In the main body of the App, I have the following code, which creates the menu entry "Plot":

```
var body: some Scene {
  WindowGroup("MainPage", id: "main-page") {
    GeneticGenealogyPage()
      .frame(minWidth: 750, maxWidth: 750, minHeight: 510, maxHeight: 510)
  }

  Window("Plot", id: "plot-page") {
    PlotViewPage()
      .frame(minWidth: 800, maxWidth: 800, minHeight: 750, maxHeight: 750)
  }
}
```

The PlotViewPage has the following structure:

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct PlotViewPage: View {
  @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow

  var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
      Text("Cumulative Distribution Function")
      VStack {
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of using a menu to bring up the plot, I would like to bring it up programmatically as soon as the calculations are complete.  How can I do that?

I have found approaches online that apparently work for iOS, but have not found an approach that works under MacOS.

Comment: What does "as soon as the calculations are complete" mean? What calculations are you doing and where are you doing it?

Comment: I am writing software that processes genealogical data (DNA match data) for the purpose of assembling an accurate family tree.  The processing involves math associated with the statistics of the matches, as well as logic in assembling a family tree.  The processing is done in the same application that creates the plot.  Currently, I wait until the processing is complete, then notify the user with a message box.  The user then creates the plot view manually through the Window menu, submenu Plot.  I would like to have the plot appear without this last manual step.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open your window from a view, you can use the [`openWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/openwindow) environment key.
To do this automatically, set a flag in your model when processing is complete. With the `task` or `onChange` view modifiers you can call a closure based on changements of an `ObservableObject`:

```
struct GeneticGenealogyPage: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow
    @StateObject var plotModel: YourPlotModel // this depends on your model

    // your code ...

    var body: some View {

        // your view code ...
        
        // use this:
        .task(id: plotModel.processingComplete) {
            if plotModel.processingComplete {
                openWindow(id: "plot-page")
            }
        }
        // or this:
        .onChange(of: plotModel.processingComplete) { complete in
            if complete {
                openWindow(id: "plot-page")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use the `id` that you gave to your `Window` in the scene declaration.

Comment: But don't I then need to press the "Plot" button to bring up the window?  I am hoping to find a solution that does not require pulling down a menu or pressing a button.  That is what I meant by "I would like to bring it up programmatically ..."

Comment: That is just an example, you can use the key in any closure of that struct, e.g. `.onChange`

Comment: I adapted my code example to do it without a button.